# ld: Mismatched ABI (not an ELF file) cannot compile

Tags: c, compilation, hp-ux, itanium

i have simple C hello world program and i wanted to compile it on HP-UX ia64 11.31,but i get the following error

```
/* Hello World program */

#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
}
```

```
cc -v +DD64 example
LPATH=/usr/lib/hpux64:/opt/langtools/lib/hpux64
 /usr/ccs/bin/ld -o a.out -u___exit -umain example -lc
ld: Mismatched ABI (not an ELF file) for example
Fatal error.
 removing /var/tmp/AAA003501
```

Comment: Name your file `example.c` and retry.

Comment: Thanks!! :) Oh my goodness i didn't even think that he needs suffix to properly compile code, i was looking for everyhing except this...

Comment: If you don't tell it explicitly what type of file you're handing it, the compiler driver will make a guess, usually based on the file extension. Looks like your compiler treats files without an extension as object code rather than source, so it assumes all you want to do is link. Your compiler's docs should contain a list of extensions it knows and how it will deal with them by default.